# Shadow Catcher + Free Style External Contour

Tags: shadows, freestyle, shadowcatcher

I want to have External Contour outlined from my scene, except for the ground, which is a shadow catcher.

How can I achieve this?
Here is the problem:
[image]

Because of the ground, the bottom contour of the cubes are not draw. How can I fix this?

Comment: Limit strokes per group and exclude the shadow catcher

Comment: It works for other types of edge selection. It doesn't work for External Contour :(